# How to prevent Hibernate from throwing ConstraintViolationException when using session.saveOrUpdate(Object)?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, constraintviolationexception

ConstraintViolationException is being thrown by hibernate when I use session.saveOrUpdate(Object).
Shouldn't the "update" part prevent this excpetion from being thrown?

I have also tried using session.delete(Object) and then session.save(Object) but the same exception is thrown.
How would I fix this?

Comment: It should always start by reading the exception stack trace, to understand why it's being thrown.

Comment: @JBNizet I understand, why it is being thrown. It's because I insert a duplicate value (as I need to update the data). I thought that the update method prevents this exception from being thrown (as it updates the value and not inserts it). Doesn't it? How would I update values in my database otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this annotation to the entity solved the issue:

```
@SQLInsert(sql="REPLACE INTO table_name (column_1,column_2) VALUES (?,?)")
```